# SQL: Something wrong with inheriting variables for NULL next-row values

Tags: mysql, mysql-8.0

I'm trying to inherit value from previous row (based on correct subscription_id + checking for IS NULL subscription_status), but something goes wrong and I get incorrect value.

Take a look at screenshot.

[image: bug_example]

If I'm not mistaken it also called *last non-null puzzle*, but [examples of possible solution](https://blog.jooq.org/2015/12/17/how-to-fill-sparse-data-with-the-previous-non-empty-value-in-sql/) for other DB provide window function with IGNORE NULLS.
But, I'm using MySQL 8.x and it doesn't support this function.

I'm sorry, but SQL fiddle doesn't provide correct text-value for variables in my code :(
https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wHanqoSCHKJHus5u6BU4DB/4

Or, you can see mistakes here:

```
SET @history_subscription_status = NULL;
SET @history_subscription_id = 0;

SELECT
    c.date,
    c.user_id,
    c.subscription_id,
    sd.subscription_status,
    (@history_subscription_id := c.subscription_id)  as 'historical_sub_id',
    (@history_subscription_status := CASE
        WHEN @history_subscription_id = c.subscription_id AND sd.subscription_status IS NULL
            THEN @history_subscription_status
        ELSE
            sd.subscription_status
        END
    ) as 'historical'
FROM
    calendar c
LEFT JOIN
    subscription_data sd ON sd.date = c.date AND sd.user_id = c.user_id AND sd.subscription_id = c.subscription_id
ORDER BY
    c.user_id,
    c.subscription_id,
    c.date
```

I expect to get results for this query in this way:

[image: expected_results]

IMPORTANT: I'm going to use this code for a lot of data (about 1 mln rows), so it very important for me to avoid additional select or subquery that can slow down the execution of the query.

Comment: Note that MySQL does not guarantee the order in which the components of a select statement are evaluated.  Your user variable logic may not happen as you expect.  I suggest maybe using window functions instead, given that you are using MySQL 8+.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Tim. Actually, I'm trying to use LAG() or LAST_VALUE(), but it doesn't work well also. That's why I fallback to variables :(

Comment: I don't have an answer, but the best way to present a SQL question here is to a) show sample input table data, and then b) show the output along with the logic to get from start to finish.

Comment: I see. Will try to prepare the example. By the way, here it is how Oracle guys resolve this problem: https://blog.jooq.org/2015/12/17/how-to-fill-sparse-data-with-the-previous-non-empty-value-in-sql/

Comment: Like this: ```last_value(nullif(subscription_status, 0)) IGNORE NULLS OVER (ORDER BY date), 0)```

Comment: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/55oDktc1ama2vUWjDJh6Hu/0 here is the similar to Orcale example, but MySQL 8 doesn't support IGNORE NULLS by now :( 
```This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'IGNORE NULLS'```

That's why I'm looking for another solution.